# Access multiple input field values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

How do you access multiple input field values using jQuery? I've fiddled with .serialize() and .formSerialize() but those are not working for me.

**Current Form Setup**

```
<form class="user__inputs hidden" id="user__activity__input">
  <label class="user__labels" id="userSteps" for="userStepsInput">Number of Steps:</label><br>
  <input aria-labelledby="userSteps" type="number" min="0" id="number__of__steps" name="userStepsInput" placeholder="Enter Steps.."><br>
  <label class="user__labels" id="userActive" for="userStepsInput">Active Minutes:</label><br>
  <input aria-labelledby="userActive" type="number" min="0" id="active__minutes" name="userStepsInput" placeholder="Enter Minutes..">
  <label class="user__labels" id="userStairs" for="userStepsInput">Flight of Stairs:</label><br>
  <input aria-labelledby="userStairs" type="number" min="0" id="flights_stairs" name="userStepsInput" placeholder="Enter Flights..">
  <input type="submit" for="userStepsInput" value="Submit" onchange="runThis()">
</form>
```

**Current jQuery Attempt**
This was to see if I can even get access to my entered values.

```
function runThis() {
  console.log($('#user__activity__input').serialize())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always good practice to keep your `HTML` and `JavaScript` separate. If all you want is to be able to see you input values you can use the following setup.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#user__activity__input').on('submit', runThis);
});

function runThis(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).serialize());
  //or validate the data before submitting it as follows:
  //this.submit();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="user__inputs hidden" id="user__activity__input">
  <label class="user__labels" id="userSteps" for="userStepsInput">Number of Steps:</label><br>
  <input aria-labelledby="userSteps" type="number" min="0" id="number__of__steps" name="userStepsInput" placeholder="Enter Steps.."><br>
  <label class="user__labels" id="userActive" for="userStepsInput">Active Minutes:</label><br>
  <input aria-labelledby="userActive" type="number" min="0" id="active__minutes" name="userStepsInput" placeholder="Enter Minutes..">
  <label class="user__labels" id="userStairs" for="userStepsInput">Flight of Stairs:</label><br>
  <input aria-labelledby="userStairs" type="number" min="0" id="flights_stairs" name="userStepsInput" placeholder="Enter Flights..">
  <input type="submit" for="userStepsInput" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the help! I'm able to get some movement with my data now. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

PeterKA has a good solution to get you moving.

To build on their answer, this will help you when dealing with the data.
It would be best to change the `for=` and respective `name=` to unique values per label/input set. Then any backend you send this form to will be able to understand what each value is.

Example:
Label: `for="userStepsInput"`
Input: `name="userStepsInput"`

Label: `for="userMinutesInput"`
Input: `name="userMinutesInput"`

Label: `for="userFlightsInput"`
Input: `name="userFlightsInput"`

This should then return `userStepsInput=3&userMinutesInput=4&userFlightsInput=3` rather than the ambiguous `userStepsInput=8&userStepsInput=4&userStepsInput=3`

Comment: Great! I ran into this and was trying to think of a work around. I really appreciate the insight!

Comment: No problem glad it helped! Once you get the hang of forms you can do alot with them and backends.